# Deploying custom Kong plugin in GKE deployed Kong API Gateway

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kong, kong-plugin

I'm looking up on the Kong API gateway and deployed a Kong instance on GKE via Google Cloud Marketplace. I want to add a custom Kong plugin to this instance and enable it for my services. How could I do it? are there any resources I could follow to get an idea on this? thank you.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using docker

you can install any plugin in kong using `luarocks`

For example here is one sample docker file

```
FROM kong
ENV LUA_PATH /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/kong-oidc/?.lua;;
# For lua-cjson
ENV LUA_CPATH /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;;

# Install unzip for luarocks, gcc for lua-cjson
RUN yum install -y unzip gcc 
RUN luarocks install luacov
```

here one example of oidc plugin : https://github.com/nokia/kong-oidc

we can install plugin using : `luarocks install <plugin name>`

build your own custom docker image and use kong image as base docker image.

here whole example working `Dockerfile`

```
FROM kong:latest  
USER root
RUN apk update && apk add git unzip luarocks
RUN luarocks install kong-oidc  
USER kong
```

by this way also you can add some of the community plugin and enterprise plugin in docker.

Answer (score 0):

You could either bake the custom plugin into your container image, or modify your Deployment manifest to download and run the plugin with `command` and `arguments` in the configuration.

For the first option, you only need to add the commands to install and run the plugin to your Dockerfile, then build an image with `docker build`. Once you have the new image, you can perform a [rolling update](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/updating-apps#updating_an_application) by using `kubectl set image deployment` or modify the workload in the Cloud Console.

Modifying the Deployment YAML would have a similar result, but you would need to add `command` and `arguments` to download and run the custom plugin whenever the container starts.

The [google-marketplace-kong-app](https://github.com/Kong/google-marketplace-kong-app) and [kong-dist-kubernetes](https://github.com/Kong/kong-dist-kubernetes) repo has instructions on how to build and deploy Kong manually. I'd recommend checking them and include your custom plugin.